# NoReverseMatch at /products/ Reverse for 'product-update' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['products/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/edit/$']

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Struggling with some code. I have seen a lot of people have had this problem, but I can't seem to get their code fixes to work with mine (of course modifying to fit my project). I am still really new to this.

I want to be able to edit a product from the list of products on product_list.html.
I have created a HTML page called product_update.html in which you can edit the product, and this works. But I would like to direct an 'Edit' link on the product_list page to that product_update page.

I am getting this error: NoReverseMatch at /products/ Reverse for 'product-update' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['products/(?P[0-9]+)/edit/$']

Here is my code:

**views.py**

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.views.generic import UpdateView

from .forms import ProductForm, RawProductForm
from .models import Product

def product_list_view(request):
queryset = Product.objects.all()
context = {
    "object_list": queryset
}

return render(request, "products/product_list.html", context)

# ------------------------------------------------------------ #

class UpdateProductView(UpdateView):
model = Product
template_name = 'products/product_update.html'
fields = ['title', 'image', 'description', 'price', 'summary', 'featured']
```

**product_list.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% for instance in object_list %}
  <p>
    {{ instance.id }} -
    <a href="{{ instance.get_absolute_url }}">{{ instance.title }}</a>
    |
    <a href="{% url 'products:product-update' %}">(Edit)</a>
    |
    <!-- <a href="">Delete</a> -->
  </p>

{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

**models.py**

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.urls import reverse
    from PIL import Image

    class Product(models.Model):
        title       = models.CharField(max_length=120) # max_length = required
        image       = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
        description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
        price       = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10000)
        summary     = models.TextField(blank=True, null=False)
        featured    = models.BooleanField(default=False)

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse("products:product-detail", kwargs={"id": self.id})
            # return f"products/{self.id}/"

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
            img = Image.open(self.image.path)

            # if img.height > 300 or img.weight > 300:
            #     output_size = (300, 300)
            #     img.thumbnail(output_size)
            #     img.save(self.image.path)
```

**urls.py**

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path

    from products.views import (
        product_detail_view,
        product_create_view,
        product_delete_view,
        product_list_view,
        dynamic_lookup_view,
        UpdateProductView,
        )

    app_name = 'products'
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', product_list_view, name='product-list'),
        path('', product_detail_view),
        path('<int:id>/', dynamic_lookup_view, name='product-detail'),
        path('<int:id>/delete/', product_delete_view, name='product-delete'),
        path('create/', product_create_view),
        path('<int:pk>/edit/', UpdateProductView.as_view(), name='product-update'),
    ]
```

**Traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/

Django Version: 3.1.3
Python Version: 3.9.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'pages',
 'products',
 'blog',
 'members']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /Users/alfiemitchell/Documents/Dev/tryDjango/src/templates/base.html, error at line 0
   Reverse for 'product-update' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['products/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/edit/$']
   1 : <!doctype html>
   2 : <html>
   3 : <head>
   4 :   <title>Try Django</title>
   5 : </head>
   6 :     <body>
   7 :       {% include 'navbar.html' %}
   8 : 
   9 :       {% block content %}
   10 :       {% endblock %}


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alfiemitchell/Documents/Dev/tryDjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/alfiemitchell/Documents/Dev/tryDjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/alfiemitchell/Documents/Dev/tryDjango/src/products/views.py", line 82, in product_list_view
    return render(request, "products/product_list.html", context)
  File "/Users/alfiemitchell/Documents/Dev/tryDjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/Users/alfiemitchell/Documents/Dev/tryDjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/Users/alfiemitchell/Documents/Dev/tryDjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/alfiemitchell/Documents/Dev/tryDjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/alfiemitchell/Documents/Dev/tryDjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/alfiemitchell/Documents/Dev/tryDjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/alfiemitchell/Documents/Dev/tryDjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/alfiemitchell/Documents/Dev/tryDjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/alfiemitchell/Documents/Dev/tryDjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/alfiemitchell/Documents/Dev/tryDjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/alfiemitchell/Documents/Dev/tryDjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/alfiemitchell/Documents/Dev/tryDjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/alfiemitchell/Documents/Dev/tryDjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/alfiemitchell/Documents/Dev/tryDjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/alfiemitchell/Documents/Dev/tryDjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 211, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/Users/alfiemitchell/Documents/Dev/tryDjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/alfiemitchell/Documents/Dev/tryDjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 446, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "/Users/alfiemitchell/Documents/Dev/tryDjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/alfiemitchell/Documents/Dev/tryDjango/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /products/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'product-update' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['products/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/edit/$']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give a primary key as a parameter to the update view. If you change the product-list.html file as follows, the problem will be solved.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% for instance in object_list %}
  <p>
    {{ instance.id }} -
    <a href="{{ instance.get_absolute_url }}">{{ instance.title }}</a>
    |
    <a href="{% url 'products:product-update' instance.pk %}">(Edit)</a>
    |
    <!-- <a href="">Delete</a> -->
  </p>

{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```